# How to switch the android music output device

Tags: android, audio, device

I'm doing some test work on android music playback. I have a headset and a bluetooth headset connect with the phone at the same time. 
Then there will be 4 output devices that can play the sound: **speaker, handset, headset, and the BT_headset.** 
What I want to know is: is there a way to switch the audio output to the 4 device using code?
I cant do switch between speaker and handset if there is no headset plugin using **audioManager.setMode()**. But, if a headset plugin the sound can not out from handset. 
Then, if the headset and bt_headset connect at the same time, the sound always out from the later connect one.

Comment: When you say BT_headset, are you talking about SCO or A2DP? I.e. is it a headset intended for voice calls only, or is it also intended for media playback?